# Android: calender not give the Full Year number and gives only 111 instead of the 2011

Tags: time, android-emulator, emulation, android

I am fetching the Year of the Current device time with this code:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
cal.getTime().getYear();
```

But with that i am getting 111 instead of the 2011 as current year.

If i have set the 2012 as current year then it gives me 112 instead of the 2012.

Why it is like that ?
Please help me for that.
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [getYear](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date.html#getYear%28%29)() returns the year since 1900. So you have to use

```
cal.getTime().getYear() + 1900
```

**EDIT**

The `Date.getYear()` is deprecated. So you can use `cal.get(Calendar.YEAR)` to get the year field. See [Date.getYear()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date.html#getYear%28%29) and [Calendar.get()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#get%28int%29)

Comment: +1. "Returns the gregorian calendar year since 1900 for this Date object." You really should use `cal.get(Calendar.YEAR) - 1900` instead though-

Comment: Thanks @Michell, I edited my answer. infact he wants year as 2011 itself. So subtraction with 1900 is not required.

Comment: Ok Thanks to both for the reply.

Comment: This method is deprecated.
use Calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR) - 1900 

Returns the gregorian calendar year since 1900 for this Date object. so this is true